# Dynamic ListView of stateful widgets not working

Tags: flutter

Dears,

it could be just a mistake of mine but ...it's driving me crazy ;)

I have a ListView inside my statefulwidget:

```
              Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              itemCount: searchableFoodList.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                print('4 - SFL - ${searchableFoodList[index].id} - ${searchableFoodList[index].name}');

                return
                  FoodItem(
                    id: searchableFoodList[index].id,
                    baseUnit: searchableFoodList[index].baseUnit,
                    baseUnitS: searchableFoodList[index].baseUnitS,
                    baseVal: searchableFoodList[index].baseVal,
                    baseValCal: searchableFoodList[index].baseValCal,
                    mediumVal: searchableFoodList[index].mediumVal,
                    mediumValCal: searchableFoodList[index].mediumValCal,
                    name: searchableFoodList[index].name,
                    note: searchableFoodList[index].note
                );
              },
            ),
```

searchableFoodList is modified (according user selection) inside a setState().

Let say that we have a 3 FoodItem(s), so my searchableFoodList is [FoodItem-1, FoodItem-2, FoodItem-3] and everything is working fine.

If I select a single item in my list, let say "FoodItem-2", the searchableFoodList becomes [FoodItem-2] and the list displayed contains (correctly) just one item but it is FoodItem-1.
Note that I inserted a print ...and it prints "FoodItem-2"

I guess that the problem is that it is considered the "original list" and it is changed only the length of the list but the list itself is not re-generated.

I have no more ideas ...any suggestions to solve this problem?

P.S.
FoodItem is stateful widget as well (an animated one). I did something similar with using stateless widget and I didn't have any problem

Comment: Try adding a key to FoodItem widget. Set the key as key: ValueKey(searchableFoodList[index].id) ie, same as id if you are sure that this id uniquely identifies the item.

Comment: GREAT!!!  I thought there was no need since "id" is an unique identifier but I was wrong ...the key is the key :) THANKS Afridi!!!